# How would I make a building tool with a grid? (ROBLOX LUA)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm somewhat new to coding in lua, and currently I'm trying to make a game where 4 teams build a base within a time limit, and then fight. And while I was able to make it so that the player could build, there is no Grid system and all teams share the same tool.

So my question is: how do I make a “build tool” that enables players to build with a grid system? I also need to somehow make it so that the respective team can only build on their respective platform.

And if possible a “ghost block” that shows where the player is about to place the block.

This is the code I got so far for the building kit:

```
-- all of this is in a localscript inside of the hammer tool

local players = game:GetService("Players")

local hammer = script.Parent -- the hammer tool that will make the player know they are in “building mode”

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local mouse = player:GetMouse() -- get the mouse from the player

local function placeBlock(Part)

    local position = mouse.Hit.p -- the position of the mouse so i can place blocks there

    local buildingBrickRed = Instance.new("Part") -- creates a part that the player will place

    buildingBrickRed.Parent = workspace

    buildingBrickRed.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red") -- makes the brick red

    buildingBrickRed.Size = Vector3.new(5, 5, 5) -- sets the size of the block

    buildingBrickRed.CFrame = CFrame.new(position) -- sets the position of the block to be where the mouse is

end

hammer.Activated:Connect(placeBlock) -- connects to the function when the player activates the tool
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how coding Roblox works, however for a grid you could change the coordinates of the mouse, (assuming this is a 3D vector as well,) by dividing them all by the brick size and rounding this value and multiplying again.

```
function griddify(coordinate)
    return math.floor(coordinate / 5) * 5
end

print(griddify(31))    -->   30
print(griddify(31.4))  -->   30
print(griddify(3141))  --> 3140
```

---

If you want to check that they are building on their platform you will have to check the *x* and *z* coordinates for being in the correct range.
And if you want to have ghost blocks you will have to display each block at the mouse coordinates, without actually building them